# Is there an equivalent of ping for checking connectivity to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Is there an equivalent of ping for checking connectivity to SQL Server?

I'm finding our BizTalk Admin Console that during some long operations, e.g. importing a big bindings file, the "connection" is being lost, i.e. the red box appears on the console. Eventually connectivity comes back. The SQL Server is on a different machine from BizTalk.

Also saw an issue where connection to SSO db was lost for a minute or so ... *worse, this was production environment!*

SQL DBA has checked and SQL is fine, showing no network issues ...

I can do a `ping -t` to see if anything happens to the connection between the two machines, but is there an equivalent function to check ongoing connectivity to SQL Server itself?

And if there is such a function, is there someway to automate its checking so I can have it flag any occurance of disconnect ... just sending an email to ops would be good first step

Answer (score 2):

You can always use PowerShell

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
$query = "SELECT top 1* from bts_application"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance '.' -Database 'BizTalkMgmtDb'
```